# How to unit test the controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the controller in ASP.NET Mvc 6.

```
    public class VendorManagementController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IVendorRespository _vendorRespository;

        public VendorManagementController(IVendorRespository vendorRespository)
        {
            _vendorRespository = vendorRespository;
        }

        [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public dynamic GetVendorById(int pkey)
        {
            Vendor vendor = _vendorRespository.GetVendor(pkey);
            return vendor;
        }

        // GET 
        // USing JqGrid
        [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public dynamic GetVendors(string sidx, string sortOrder, int page, int rows, int pkey)
        {
            var vendors = _vendorRespository.GetAllVendors().AsQueryable();
            var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            var pageSize = rows;
            var totalRecords = vendors.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
            return something
        }

        // POST
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string PostVendor(Vendor item)
        {
             _vendorRespository.AddVendor(item);
        }
```

The [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api) provides an example to test the controller, but it uses `HttpRequestMessage`. It doesn't fit my case.

So if I want to test the return Vendors, how?
Say I have the method:

```
 [Fact]
    public void GetAllVendors_ShouldReturnAllVendors()
    {
        var testVendors = GetTestVendors();
        var vendorRespository = new VendorRespository();
        var controller = new VendorManagementController(vendorRespository);
    }
```

The thing is

```
    var vendors = _vendorRespository.GetAllVendors().AsQueryable();
```

from the databse, how to mock up it with my fake vendors?

**EDIT:**

The method returns dynamic type, I can't get the Count of the list.
[image]

Comment: `controller.GetVendors()`? It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @CodeCaster, no.That methods needs a lot of parameters.Should mock them?

Comment: **What** do you want to test? If you want to test what that action method returns, you must call it. You mock dependencies, such as the repository, so you can verify that the action method calls the appropriate method on the repository.

Comment: @CodeCaster, say I created three fake vendors. I want to assert the count is 3.

Comment: Yeah, so `Assert.Equal(3, controller.GetVendors(...).Count)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, so how about `string sidx, string sortOrder, int page, int rows, int pkey`?

Comment: Again, **what do you want to test**? I'm fairly sure that you don't want to test that _"The action method GetVendors() returns three vendors regardless of the actual parameters"_. Method parameters are part of the test input, so you must provide actual values that correspond to your test. Please [edit] your question and explain explicitly, in text, full on sentences, what you want to test.

Comment: @CodeCaster well, you *could*, but it seems like a waste of time. Love, I would suggest creating a Fake/Mock Repository that uses strongly-typed lists/properties to use for testing. It's pretty quick to set up.

Comment: @CodeCaster, the thing is `var vendors = _vendorRespository.GetAllVendors().AsQueryable();` from the databse, how to mock up it with my fake vendors?

Comment: Now _that_ is a clear question, and fortunately it's been answered before. Try searching. :)

Comment: Yes, but what is the `dynamic` type actually when it leaves GetVendors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a mocking framework such as Moq from nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/.

```
using Moq;

[Fact]
public void GetAllVendors_ShouldReturnAllVendors()
{
    var testVendors = GetTestVendors();
    var vendorRespository = new Mock<IVendorRepository>();
    vendorRepository.Setup(m => m.GetAllVendors()).Returns(new List<Vendor> { new Vendor() }); // Guessing a bit on return types
    var controller = new VendorManagementController(vendorRespository.Object);

    var result = controller.GetVendors( ... )

    // Assert you get 1 Vendor back, not sure what you're planning to return by "something". :-)
}
```

Other frameworks are available, NSubsititute, FakeItEasy

Comment: I tried it, the thing is the method return `dynamic`, I can't get the `Count`

Comment: If you give me a more complete example I'll try and get it out for you. I couldn't work out what you meant by `something` :-)

Comment: I mean that the intellisense doesn't pop out the Count property. I will update the question. Hopefully remove the downvote.

Comment: It's `return something` I cant work out, if it was (say in MVC) an ActionResult I could work out how to get to the model and interogate it to check it populated properly (if it even has a list on it), without the return type in the question i cant get much further :-)

Comment: @Love Even though Intellisense doesn't give you the Count property, it's still there. That's just how dynamic works. You just need to manually write the Count and assuming that `result` has a Count property it will work. On a side note you shouldn't use dynamic anyways. If you know you're going to return a Vendor, then change the method signature to return a vendor.

Comment: @NikolaiDante, I don't know why the test is not working. It is not a separate unit test project.(It seems asp.net mvc doesn't support it in DNX version) I put it in the web application folder.

Comment: Do you have a complete, runnable example you can share e.g. github? I'm happy to run it through my IDE when I get home.